# Use three prompt boxes to ask the user for three different words and then place them in an array. Use an alert box to display the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, I'm new to JS and currently taking courses. My instructor listed one solution, and the solution I came up with in my opinion is more ideal...I used push() method which I'd think is better. And I used Template literal inside my alert method to prevent the need to concat the string and variable.... Please let me know what the better code would be! Much appreciated!

```
//Instructor's solution:
const item1 = prompt('Item 1?');
const item2 = prompt('Item2?');
const item3 = prompt('Item3?');
const myArray = [item1, item2, item3];
alert("My shopping list is:"  + myArray);
```

```
//My solution:
let shoppingList = [];
shoppingList.push(prompt('Item 1?'));
shoppingList.push(prompt('Item 2?'));
shoppingList.push(prompt('Item 3?'));
alert(`My shopping list is: ${shoppingList}`);
```

Comment: Both are fine. Using a template literal doesn't automatically make anything better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This part is better in the instructor's version

The instructor is storing the inputs separately, which is conventional. That gives them variable names, which is helpful for future programmers (since, in general, the prompt text may not be the perfect programmer-facing summary).

The array is created as a const, which is good practice when you know you are not going to reassign the whole array.

```
const item1 = prompt('Item 1?');
const item2 = prompt('Item 2?');
const item3 = prompt('Item 3?');
const myArray = [item1, item2, item3];
```

#### This part, I prefer in your version

You are using an easier-to-read layout with the template string.

And of course you have a better variable name!

```
alert(`My shopping list is: ${shoppingList}`);
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. I completely understand now that you've explained it. Good practice to assign the responses as variable instead of just pushing directly from the users input. Also - thank you for the compliment!